# È corretto dire "tenere conto questo"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, prepositions

In *La spirale*, una "cosmicomica" di Italo Calvino ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Certo, vivevo un po’ concentrato in me stesso, questo è vero, non c’è paragone con la vita di relazione che si fa adesso; e ammetto pure d’esser stato – un po’ per l’età, un po’ per influsso dell’ambiente – quel che si dice leggermente narcisista; insomma stavo lì a osservarmi tutto il tempo, vedevo in me tutti i pregi e tutti i difetti, e mi piacevo, sia negli uni sia negli altri; termini di confronto non ne avevo, va tenuto conto anche *di* questo.

La presenza della preposizione *di* in questa frase ha attirato la mia attenzione perché io ho sempre pensato che si potesse dire "tenere conto questo" senza tale preposizione. Per questa ragione, ho cercato informazioni sull'espressione "tenere conto" sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conto2/) ed ecco quello che ho trovato:

> *tenere conto* (seguito da un complemento di specificazione o da una prop. introdotta dall’espressione *del fatto che* o semplicem. da *che*), fare la debita valutazione di una circostanza: *bisogna tener conto delle sue reazioni; tieni conto (del fatto) che è già molto tardi*

Cioè, uno degli esempi dal Treccani viene costruito con la preposizione articolata "della", ma non so se sarebbe anche corretto omettere tale preposizione. Insomma, la mia domanda è: sarebbe giusto dire "tenere conto questo" oppure si deve dire "tenere conto *di* questo"?

Comment: Si vede non solo la parola "conto", ma anche "[tenere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tenere_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)": *tenere conto (di qualcosa o qualcuno)*

Comment: _tenere conto questo_ mi suona sgrammaticato

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> tenere conto (seguito da un complemento di specificazione o da una prop. introdotta dall’espressione del fatto che o semplicem. da che), fare la debita valutazione di una circostanza: bisogna tener conto delle sue reazioni; tieni conto (del fatto) che è già molto tardi

Quindi dopo "tenere conto" o c'è "che" o c'è sempre un complemento di specificazione; citando ancora [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/complemento-di-specificazione_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/):

> SPECIFICAZIONE, COMPLEMENTO DI
>
> Nell’analisi logica, il complemento di specificazione indica una persona, un oggetto o un fatto che servono a specificare, precisare meglio il significato della parola da cui dipende. Può istituire numerosi tipi di rapporti: i più comuni sono quello attributivo (la luce del giorno), di possesso (la casa di Franco), di parentela (la madre di Giulio), di pertinenza (questo è compito della polizia) ecc. È introdotto dalla preposizione di

"È introdotto dalla preposizione di" va inteso come "È *sempre* introdotto dalla preposizione di": non esiste un caso in cui non succeda.

Quindi se dopo "tenere conto" c'è un complemento di specificazione (il che succede in tutti i casi tranne il caso in cui c'è "che"), "di" ("del"/"dello"/"degli"/"della"/"delle") *devono* essere presenti affinché il complemento di specificazione possa essere introdotto in un modo grammaticalmente corretto; quindi non può esistere un caso in cui "tenere conto" sia seguito da un qualcosa che non sia "che" senza che quest'ultimo non sia preceduto da una preposizione.

Comment: +1, completissimo. Solo per aggiungere un commento che forse aiuta l'intuizione: la locuzione “tenere conto” ha come origine trasparente il fatto di “registrare gli addendi, o altri termini, di un calcolo”. Così come si tiene (il) conto delle spese sostenute per qualcosa, così si tiene conto di altri fattori più astratti.

Comment: È veramente curioso per me perché è diverso dalla mia lingua.

Comment: @DaG Sì, sicuramente aiuta

Comment: @Charo Nemmeno nel caso citato da DaG? in Italiano sempre, a meno che anche Treccani non se lo sia perso; non mi viene in mente un caso in cui non si usi.

Comment: +1. La particella "ne" puo sostituire un oggetto, preceduto da "di" (*ne tener conto - tenerne conto*), e in tal caso qualunque  cosa segue, non viene preceduta da una preposizione.

Comment: @I.M. Hmmm in realtà quei due casi potrebbero esserlo, perché il complemento di specificazione, se non implicito, potrebbe essere esplicitato dopo il verbo (nota che "ne tener conto" è scorretto; vale solo per le forme coniugate: "ne *tengo* conto", "ne *hai tenuto* conto", "ne *tenne* conto", ...): "Ne tengo conto *di* andare in banca" - "Devo ricordarmi *di* tenerne conto *di* andare in banca"

Comment: @kos: Nella mia lingua si dice "tenir en compte alguna cosa" senza preposizione.

Comment: @Charo Aspetta perché forse ci stiamo confondendo: Google Traduttore mi da la seguente traduzione di "tenir en compte alguna cosa" (dal Catalano): "prendere *in* considerazione qualcosa" =~ "tenere *in* considerazione qualcosa" =~ "tenere *in* conto qualcosa"; se Google Traduttore non ha sbagliato stiamo parlando di due cose diverse, "tenere *in* conto qualcosa" è una forma diversa e *non* vuole la preposizione dopo neanche in Italiano; [cont]

Comment: [cont] con riferimento al tuo esempio, "tenere conto questo" =  sbagliato, "tenere conto *di* questo" = corretto, "tenere *in* conto questo" = corretto (ma è una forma diversa), "tenere *in* conto *di* questo" = sbagliato (ma è una forma scorretta della seconda forma)

Comment: @kos: Hmmm... Forse dovrebbe fare una domanda sulla differenza tra "tenere conto" e "tenere in conto". "Tenir en compte alguna cosa" significa considerare questa "cosa", averla presente nel momento di agire o di prendere una decisione.

Comment: @Charo Se vuoi ovviamente fai pure la domanda, soprattutto se vuoi una risposta approfondita, comunque (spoiler): sono la stessa identica cosa, si tratta solo di due modi diversi (a livello grammaticale) di dire la stessa cosa; uno prende un complemento di specificazione, l'altro un complemento oggetto (come in Catalano? (suppongo completamente a orecchio); ora capisco perché ti tornava strano, semplicemente quella che hai citato è una forma diversa da quella che sarebbe forse la più corrispondente al Catalano "tenir en compte alguna cosa", ovvero "tenere *in* conto")

Comment: Personalmente non ho presente la locuzione “tenere in conto” (se non in frasi fatte come “tenere in gran conto qualcuno”), ma se esiste si costruisce senz'altro come dice kos. Tornando all'esempio dei conti veri e propri, qui stiamo dicendo, per esempio, che “teniamo/mettiamo nel computo” anche il tal addendo. È una differenza simile a quella che c'è tra “mettere in mano (un oggetto)” e “mettere mano (a un lavoro)”.

Comment: @DaG Sulla costruzione metto un attimo le mani avanti finchè non trovo una fonte migliore della mia opinione, comunque per come l'ho sempre sentito va sempre con un complemento oggetto tipo "tieni in conto *il fatto che* ..." e in particolare con una proposizione relativa tipo "tieni in conto *che* ..."; comunque avendo avuto il sospetto che fosse un'espressione locale ho controllato e sembrerebbe abbastanza diffuso anche secondo ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tenere+in+conto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: Perfetto, kos, grazie per la verifica su “tenere in conto”!

Comment: Non *fate conto su di me* per chiarire la cosa (anzi son venuto a complicarla perfino).