# Ci sono differenze tra "tenere conto" e "tenere in conto"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, meaning

Nei commenti a questa [risposta a una mia domanda sull'espressione "tenere conto"](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5798/707) si è menzionata la locuzione "tenere in conto". Io però non capisco bene se ci sono differenze di uso o di significato tra queste due espressioni. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Comment: Non ho mai sentito "tenere in conto" ma sentendola per la prima volta ho pensato a una variante di "tenere conto di" o "tenere/prendere in considerazione" ed effettivamente una ricerca superficiale su Google sembra confermarlo.

Comment: Sembra che anche in francese esistano due espressioni: ["tenir compte de" e "prendre en compte"](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1996/6354).

Comment: *Tener conto vs tenere in conto.* Secondo https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tenere+conto%2Ctenere+in+conto&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctenere%20conto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctenere%20in%20conto%3B%2Cc0  tenere in conto è un'espressione molto meno usata. A me sembrano sinonimi.

Comment: @Charo - se guardi nei vari esempi in Ngram, puoi constatare che le due espressioni sono usate con lo stesso significato, l'unica differenza è che "in conto" è molto meno usata.

Comment: ***Tenere conto*** (di qualcosa o qualcuno) [sottoporre qualcosa alla propria considerazione: tieni conto dei suoi consigli] ≈ considerare (ø), prendere (o tenere) in considerazione (ø), tenere presente (ø)..http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tenere_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/ - Probabilmente la preposizione ***in*** viene usata in simpatia con l'espressione analoga ***tenere in considerazione***.

Comment: **Tenere conto** [*di* qualcosa/qualcuno | *che* + subordinata] = considerare, tenere a mente ("Prima di decidere, *tieni conto* di tutti i vantaggi e gli svantaggi"). **Tenere *in* conto** [qualcosa/qualcuno] = avere un'alta considerazione ("Prima di decidere, consulto sempre Mario perché *tengo in gran conto* la sua opinione"). **Tenere *da* conto** [qualcosa/qualcuno] = conservare, custodire ("Sono molto affezinato a quel libro, *tienimelo da conto*, mentre sono via"). **Fare conto** [*che* + congiuntivo | *di* + infinito] = immaginare, far finta ("Ignoralo, *fai conto* che neppure esista")

Answer (score 2):

"Tenere conto di X" e "Tenere in conto X indicano entrambi scenari dove bisogna considerare anche X come fattore che ha un effetto su qualcosa -> "Per spiegare la crisi economica, bisogna tenere conto della situazione politica" / "Per spiegare la crisi economica, bisogna tenere in conto la situazione politica".

"Tenere da conto X" indica uno scenario in cui X è un oggetto di valore che bisogna conservare con riguardo -> "Ti ho prestato il mio libro preferito, tienilo da conto!".

Comment: Tenere in conto non ha il significato di tenere da conto. Tenere in conto significa tenere in considerazione. Tenere da conto significa mettere da parte, custodire.

Comment: @Josh61 sì, ho scritto la cosa sbagliata (è mattina...^_^ ). Ora è corretto.

Comment: Come è corretta la risposta di piffy.

Comment: @Josh61 La risposta di piffy è corretta sulle prime due, ma sembra dare a "tenere da conto" lo stesso significato, da cui la mia risposta per chiarire la differenza.

Comment: Sì, 'da conto' ha un significato diverso. le altre due sono di fatto sinonimi.

Comment: @kos: Ricorda che la domanda è sull'espressione "tenere conto (di...)", no su "tenere di conto".

Comment: @Charo Grazie, mi ero confuso; rifraso

Comment: Sono d'accordo; credo che "tenere conto di" si associ più a un qualcosa da fare per soddisfare prettamente una prassi, e che "tenere in conto" si associ più a un qualcosa da fare per una motivazione sentita come un po' più importante (forse la motivazione per la quale è necessario "tenere conto" o "tenere in conto" stessa, in funzione della sua importanza, determina quale delle due è più corretto usare).

Comment: @kos: Perlomeno esiste la differenza di uso di tipo grammaticale (uso intransitivo/transitivo) che hai menzionato tu nei commenti a [questo post](http://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5798/707). Sarebbe interessante riportarla anche qui.

Comment: @Charo Hai ragione, lo faccio appena trovo una fonte; come ho già detto anche nei commenti alla mia risposta metto temporaneamente le mani avanti sulla costruzione, proprio perché vorrei dare una risposta precisa.

Comment: Scusate, l'errore è mio. Tendo a usare le due espressioni in modo intercambiabile ma dopo un po' di ricerche (e chiacchiere con mia moglie) ho visto che non è così. Kudos per Josh

Answer (score 1):

Dal punto di vista del significato, non c'è nessuna differenza.

Personalmente uso "tenere conto", che è molto più usato. "Tenere in conto" o  "tenere da conto" mi danno l'idea di essere un po' antiquate e/o affettate.

Potrebbero essere però più utilizzate in altre regioni (es: il mezzogiorno), ma non ho la competenza per dirlo con certezza.

Comment: IMHO c'è differenza. Vedi la mia risposta.

Comment: Nel senso: non c'è differenza tra "in conto" e "conto di", ma c'è differenza con "da conto"

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia         "Da conto" non c'entra con la domanda. È un'espressione diversa.

Comment: @Josh61 anche se non è il suo significato primario "tenere da conto" è anche un sinomimo di "tenere in conto" (cfr. http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/T/tenere.shtml?refresh_ce-cp)

Comment: @piffy - potresti 'copy and paste' la parte dove questo viene evidenziato?

Answer (score 0):

C'è anche da considerare il ruolo dei cosiddetti 'transfer' o interferenze, per esempio in spagnolo si dice 'tener en cuenta'. Da qui, ne viene fuori che le regioni con forte dominazione spagnola hanno conservato nel substrato della loro parlata l'espressione 'tenere in conto' che si è fusa con la più corretta 'tenere conto di qualcosa' dell'italiano standard.

Comment: bravissimo, grazie ;))
È la più chiara esposizione in assoluto di quelle che ho letto, voglio dire i colleghi hanno contribuito anche loro, ma la sua, se mi permette il'tu' Vittorio, è la più esauriente. Grazie mille di nuovo!