# "Costruito" oppure "costrutto"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5797/707), quando ho scritto la frase

> Cioè, uno degli esempi dal Treccani viene *costruito* con la preposizione articolata "della", ma non so se sarebbe anche corretto omettere tale preposizione

ho avuto il dubbio se fosse corretto usare il vocabolo "costruito" o se si dovesse invece usare "costrutto". I siti web che coniugano verbi danno tanto "costruito" quanto "costrutto" come participio passato del verbo "costruire" e su Google Libri si trovano esempi di frasi con "viene costruito", ma anche di frasi con "viene costrutto" (forse questi sono più antichi). Sono entrambi corretti? Ci sono differenze di uso tra uno e l'altro?

Comment: Come curiosità non attinente alla domanda aggiungo che un costrutto è, usato come nome comune, un tipo di creatura di molti universi fantasy (es. Dungeons and Dragons), e si tratta di mostri costruiti, appunto, in diverse forme e materiali, ed in seguito magicamente animati. Fra di essi ci sono i golem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Costrutto è molto meno usato di costruito come p.p. di costruire come evidenziato da Treccani e come risulta da Ngram:

***[Costruire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/costruire_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/):***

> - v. tr. [dal lat. construĕre, der. di struĕre "ammassare, costruire", col pref. con-] (io costruisco, tu costruisci, ecc.; pass. rem. costruìi o costrussi, costruisti, ecc.; ***part. pass. costruito*** o, ***meno com., costrutto).***

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A8%20costruito%2C%C3%A8%20costrutto%2Cviene%20costruito%2Cviene%20costrutto&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A8%20costruito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A8%20costrutto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cviene%20costruito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cviene%20costrutto%3B%2Cc0): costruito vs costrutto.

[Costrutto](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/costrutto.shtml) viene più comunemente usato come sostantivo nei seguenti casi:

> - (gramm.) Disposizione, ordine dei sintagmi nella frase: un ampio costrutto; struttura sintattica: *costrutto irregolare*.
> - (estens.) Significato logico di una frase, di un'espressione (sinonimi) senso, coerenza: *discorso senza costrutto.*
> - (fig.) Risultato concreto, proficuo (sinonimi) profitto: *spendere senza costrutto.*
>     • sec. XIV